# Multiple image selection using Ctrl+Click and uploading using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to implement a Facebook-style multiple image uploader in my PHP application. It should be possible to select multiple files using Ctrl+click.
Is there any jQuery plugin that I can use or any sample code I can refer to?

Please help
Thank You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really possible using a conventional file upload field. You're going to need to use a Flash based upload system. Please consider something like [YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/). It is a Javascript library wrapped around a special file upload system contained in a flash movie. It's remarkably easy to use. There's probably plenty of other alternatives out there too.

**EDIT:** There *is* HTML5 functionality for multiple file upload fields now. You can do it like this:

```
<input type="file" multiple="true" />
```

Of course this isn't going to be well supported in all browsers. There might be a JS upload library out there that uses HTML5 and then falls back on Flash where HTML5 is not available. May the Google be with you :)

Comment: Good answer, better delete mine :)

Answer (score 0):

with [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) you can have the ability to select multiple files for upload. it uses some flash too.